# Reading a file character by character in C

Tags: c, file-io, io, iostream

I'm writing a BF interpreter in C and I've run into a problem reading files. I used to use `scanf` in order to read the first string, but then you couldn't have spaces or comments in your BF code.

Right now here is what I have.

```
char *readFile(char *fileName)
{
  FILE *file;
  char *code = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
  file = fopen(fileName, "r");
  do 
  {
    *code++ = (char)fgetc(file);

  } while(*code != EOF);
  return code;
}
```

I know the problem arises in how I'm assigning the next char in the file to the code pointer but I'm just not sure what that is.
My pointer knowledge is lacking  which is the point of this exercise.
The interpreter works fine, all using pointers, I'm just having a problem reading files in to it.

(I'm going to implement only reading `+-><[].,` into the file later, although if anyone has a good way to do it, it would be great if you'd let me know!)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your code:

```
char *readFile(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *file;
    char *code = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    do 
    {
      *code++ = (char)fgetc(file);

    } while(*code != EOF);
    return code;
}
```

1. What if the file is greater than 1,000 bytes?
2. You are increasing `code` each time you read a character, and you return `code` back to the caller (even though it is no longer pointing at the first byte of the memory block as it was returned by `malloc`).
3. You are casting the result of `fgetc(file)` to `char`. You need to check for `EOF` before casting the result to `char`.

It is important to maintain the original pointer returned by `malloc` so that you can free it later. If we disregard the file size, we can achieve this still with the following:

```
char *readFile(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char *code;
    size_t n = 0;
    int c;

    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL; //could not open file

    code = malloc(1000);

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        code[n++] = (char) c;
    }

    // don't forget to terminate with the null character
    code[n] = '\0';        

    return code;
}
```

There are various system calls that will give you the size of a file; a common one is [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html).

Comment: Whats the easiest way to count the number of characters in a file so I can set the "1000" to that? Also I'm not exactly sure what you mean by number 2, I understand that i'm doing it wrong in that way, but how would i amend that?

Comment: @pwnmonkey: What I mean is that you are returning `code` while it is pointing to the *end* of the file, not while it is pointing to the beginning.

Comment: @deamlax You seem to have a small typo on your example. `fgets` requires more than one argument. You meant `fgetc` perhaps?

Comment: I had to cast malloc as `code = (char*)malloc(1000);` because I got error converting char* to void in c++

Comment: @A.k. if you are using C++, don't use `malloc` at all. Read files using `std::istream`, and use `std::vector<char>` or another structure to handle buffers. Use `new char[]` as a last resort, but avoid `malloc` when writing C++ code because there are better (type safe) alternatives :)

Answer (score 12):

Expanding upon the above code from @dreamlax

```
char *readFile(char *fileName) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char *code;
    size_t n = 0;
    int c;

    if (file == NULL) return NULL; //could not open file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long f_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    code = malloc(f_size);

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        code[n++] = (char)c;
    }

    code[n] = '\0';        

    return code;
}
```

This gives you the length of the file, then proceeds to read it character by character.

Comment: Can you explain how fseek and ftell work? I would think you would need some kind of loop to count the characters of the file.

Comment: Think of `fseek` as a way to reposition a cursor. fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); puts the cursor at the end of the file, then `ftell` tells you where the cursor is. That gives you the size of the file. `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);` puts the cursor back at the beginning of the file so it can be read. If you do not do that, you will start reading the file from the end, which will cause errors and ruin the entire operation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one simple way to ignore everything but valid brainfuck characters:

```
#define BF_VALID "+-><[].,"

if (strchr(BF_VALID, c))
    code[n++] = c;
```

Comment: Yeah I was using this before, but the problem is that if the file has newlines in it its puts those newlines within the string. Which is bad if I wanted to write the pure BF code to a file in one line, or even print it to the console.

Comment: @pwnmonkey: No, this will not store any newline characters into the destination string (if you added a `\n` to `BF_VALID`, it would).

Answer (score 3):

the file is being opened and not closed for each call to the function also

Comment: Yeah I know, I had already changed that but thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most significant problem is that you're incrementing `code` as you read stuff in, and then returning the final value of `code`, i.e. you'll be returning a pointer to the *end* of the string.  You probably want to make a copy of `code` before the loop, and return that instead.

Also, C strings need to be null-terminated.  You need to make sure that you place a `'\0'` directly after the final character that you read in.

**Note:** You could just use `fgets()` to get the entire line in one hit.

Comment: Right but I'm going to exclude anything that isn't BF code, so it's easier to go through it in one run.

Answer (score 1):

Either of the two should do the trick -

```
char *readFile(char *fileName)
{
  FILE *file;
  char *code = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
  char *p = code;
  file = fopen(fileName, "r");
  do 
  {
    *p++ = (char)fgetc(file);
  } while(*p != EOF);
  *p = '\0';
  return code;
}

char *readFile(char *fileName)
{
  FILE *file;
  int i = 0;
  char *code = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
  file = fopen(fileName, "r");
  do 
  {
    code[i++] = (char)fgetc(file);
  } while(code[i-1] != EOF);
  code[i] = '\0'
  return code;
}
```

Like the other posters have pointed out, you need to ensure that the file size does not exceed 1000 characters. Also, remember to free the memory when you're done using it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is twofold

- **a)** you increment the pointer before you check the value read in, and
- **b)** you ignore the fact that `fgetc()` returns an int instead of a char.

The first is easily fixed:

```
char *orig = code; // the beginning of the array
// ...
do {
  *code = fgetc(file);
} while(*code++ != EOF);
*code = '\0'; // nul-terminate the string
return orig; // don't return a pointer to the end
```

The second problem is more subtle -`fgetc` returns an int so that the `EOF` value can be distinguished from any possible char value. Fixing this uses a temporary int for the `EOF` check and probably a regular while loop instead of do / while.

Comment: If `EOF` is anything between -1 and -128, then that *is* representable as a `char` value (assuming the implementation's plain `char` type is signed). In this case, conversion from an `int` to `char` is fully defined when the value is representable by a `char`, which may be the case with `EOF`.