# Editing a file after a certain character in C

Tags: c, file, edit

I'm just starting to learn C and I'm trying to write a program that will read in a file of integers represented in ASCII and add a space after the `-` sign for each negative number.

For example, the input file contains the following:

```
200
300 
-145629 
67
11111111
-1
8000
0
```

and I want the output to be:

```
200 
300 
- 145629 
67 
11111111 
- 1 
8000 
0
```

(spaces after the `-` signs).

Comment: Show us some code where you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Read from one file one `char` at a time, append a space after each `'-'` and write to another file.

Comment: Can you make a program to read the file line by line, and then output the contents to `stdout`? And then change the program to add a space after the minus sign, on the lines you have it. If you can do that, then you can come back.

Comment: I know how to read from a program line by line and output it. How can I read it character by character? Should I still us fscanf()? Also, how can I append a space? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4823177/1461424

Comment: I tried to make a while loop that iterates through the file character by character using while((c = fgetc(fdtemp)) != EOF) but it is not even entering that loop. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way will be using a while loop.

Read one char in each iteration, and if it is not '-', just out put it. If it is a '-', out put a space after out put the '-'.

Loop end with EOF.

I'm just suggesting the "easiest" way, if you are not familiar with other functions.

Comment: This is not a real answer. This is at most comment worthy.

Comment: Considering he has just learned C for a little time, I think it is the "easiest" way.

Comment: If you really want to spoon-feed, you can do it in the comments. I have done that too.

Comment: Oops   I forget that :P

Comment: How can I implement this with code? Like I said, I'm new with C and pretty lost. Thanks.

Comment: try to look up fprintf and fscanf. They are quite useful in this case.