# Cannot get Call to Function Working

Tags: c, function, input

I found this piece of code at [Reading a file character by character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823177/reading-a-file-character-by-character-in-c) and it compiles and is what I wish to use.  My problem that I cannot get the call to it working properly. The code is as follows:

```
char *readFile(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r");
    char *code;
    size_t n = 0;
    int c;

    if (file == NULL)
        return NULL; //could not open file
    code = malloc(1500);

    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        code[n++] = (char) c;
    }
    code[n] = '\0';

    return code;
}
```

I am not sure of how to call it.  Currently I am using the following code to call it: 

    .....

```
char * rly1f[1500];
char * RLY1F;    // This is the Input File Name
rly1f[0] = readFile(RLY1F);
if (rly1f[0] == NULL) { 
    printf ("NULL array); exit;
}
int n = 0;
while (n++ < 1000)  {
    printf ("%c", rly1f[n]);
}
.....
```

How do I call the readFile function such that I have an array (rly1f) which is not NULL?  The file RLY1F exists and has data in it.  I have successfully opened it previously using 'in line code' not a function.
Thanks

Comment: `printf ("NULL array); exit;` might not compile.

Comment: currently `RLY1F` isn't doing anything. It's just an empty `char *` pointer. You need to assign it the name of the text file. Something like `char *RLY1F = "myfile.txt";`

Comment: Note that `rly1f` is an array of `char` **pointers**, so `printf ("%c", rly1f[n]);` is undefined because you got a format specifier mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're experiencing is that you forgot to pass a valid filename. So either the program crashes, or `fopen` tries to open a trashed name and returns `NULL`

```
char * RLY1F;    // This is not initialized!
RLY1F = "my_file.txt";  // initialize it!
```

The next problem you'll have will be in your loop to print the characters.

You have defined an array of pointers `char * rly1f[1500];`

You read 1 file and store it in the first pointer of the array `rly1f[0]`

But when you display it you display the pointer values as characters which is not what you want. You should just do:

```
while (n < 1000)  {
    printf ("%c", rly1f[0][n]);
    n++;
    }
```

note: that would not crash but would print trash if the file read is shorter than 1000.
(BLUEPIXY suggested the post-incrementation fix for `n` BTW or first character is skipped)

So do it more simply since your string is nul-terminated, pass the array to `puts`:

```
puts(rly1f[0]);
```

EDIT: you have a problem when reading your file too. You `malloc` 1500 bytes, but you read the file fully. If the file is bigger than 1500 bytes, you get buffer overflow.

You have to compute the length of the file *before* allocating the memory. For instance like this (using `stat` would be a better alternative maybe):

```
char *readFile(char *fileName, unsigned int *size) {
...
fseek(file,0,SEEK_END); // set pos to end of file
*size = ftell(file);  // get pos, i.e. size
rewind(file);  // set pos to 0
code = malloc(*size+1);  // allocate the proper size plus one
```

notice the extra parameter which allows you to return the size as well as the file data.

Note: on windows systems, text files use `\r\n` (CRLF) to delimit lines, so the allocated size will be higher than the number of characters read if you use text mode (`\r\n` are converted to `\n` so there are less chars in your buffer: you could consider a `realloc` once you know the exact size to shave off the unused allocated space).

Comment: of course. Anyway, that would print trash if the file is smaller. I'll edit that (leaving that to explain OP mistake or he'll be confused)

Comment: Also `n` must not exceed index of `\0`.

Comment: that's covered by the allocation in the read file function: `code = malloc(1500);` argh what's not covered is that the OP ignores the real size of his/her file!!!

Comment: Thank you so much I was getting confused.  I am confused about an array, I thought its name was a pointer to it.  If so why is rly1f[0][n] required wouldn't rly1f[n] work?

Comment: nope. You have defined an array of arrays somehow. like bi-dimensional (not very academic, but just to make you understand). Doing `rly1f[n]` would provide you an uninitialized pointer. Only the first element of your pointer array is initialized. Your structure could hold 1500 files of 1500 bytes each.

Comment: Maybe I should not have 'defined' it as an array of arrays.  Maybe the code could just use an array of 'characters'.  How would I define just an 'array' of 'characters', would the 'function' 'readFile' have to change?

Comment: no your `readFile` function interface wouldn't have to change (but the contents have to, see my remarks about computing file size to allocate the proper memory chunk). You don't need that array of pointers, just a pointer.